# JavaScript - mouseover & mouseout images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple program that allows me to mouse over one image to see another. I am really struggling with how the how to handle the first on mouseover function.  I realize imageNode is undeclared, but I don't know where to declare it and what reference it is going to store.

If anyone out there could point me in the right direction to get have image1 replaced with another image in the HTML on mouseover and then return to image1 on mouseout, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm really lost right now.

I have included the HTML as well as the JavaScript below.

Thanks so much,

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id);
};

window.onload = function() {
 var image1 = $("image1");
 var image2 = $("image2");
 
 // preload images
 var links = $("image_list").getElementsByTagName("a");
 var i,
  link,
     image;
 for ( i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  link = links[i];
  image = new Image();
  image.src = link.href;
 }

 // attach mouseover and mouseout events for each image
 image1.onmouseover = function(evt) {
  link = this; //this is image that is mouseover
  // set new image
   //imageNode.src = link.getAttribute("href"

 };
 image1.onmouseout = function() {

 };

 image2.onmouseover = function() {

 };
 image2.onmouseout = function() {

 };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Rollover</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rollover.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rollover.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Fishing Images</h1>
        <p>Move your mouse over an image to change it and back out of the
            image to restore the original image.</p>
        <ul id="image_list">
            <li><a href="images/release.jpg" title="Catch and Release"></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/deer.jpg" title="Deer at Play"></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/hero.jpg" title="The Big One!"></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/bison.jpg" title="Grazing Bison"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <img id="image1" src="images/hero.jpg" alt="">
            <img id="image2" src="images/bison.jpg" alt="">
        </p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

one.

Comment: This is possible without javascript - would you be interested in a non-javascript approach?

Comment: Pure CSS can do it in this generation.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/2q8n06yu/3/

Comment: @DacreDenny 
The CSS does the same thing, but I'm working from an exercise in a book right now that says: 
" Add code to the mouseover and mouseout event handlers for the two image elements that are displayed on the page. The image element with id “image1” should display the release.jpg image when the mouse is over it and the hero.jpg image otherwise. The image element with id “image2” should display the deer.jpg image when the mouse is over it and the bison.jpg image otherwise"

Answer (score 0):

If you have some html like `<div id="image-rollover"></div>`,
you can switch out the image on hover like this using only css:

```
#image-rollover {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url('SOME_IMG_URL');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#image-rollover:hover {
  background-image: url('SOME_OTHER_IMG_URL');
}
```

Example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wo3m678f/15/)

Comment: That totally would work! I am trying to figure out an exercise in a book that I'm working in that says:

 " Add code to the mouseover and mouseout event handlers for the two image elements that are displayed on the page. The image element with id “image1” should display the release.jpg image when the mouse is over it and the hero.jpg image otherwise. The image element with id “image2” should display the deer.jpg image when the mouse is over it and the bison.jpg image otherwise"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Javascript by a simple method:

```
var imgOnMouseOver = "OVER_IMG_URI";
var imgOnMouseOut = "OUT_IMG_URI";

var container = document.getElementById("IMG_TAG_ID");
container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    container.setAttribute("src", imgOnMouseOver);
});
container.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    container.setAttribute("src", imgOnMouseOut);
});
```

Example program works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/praveen17/tv8xu67f/2/

Comment: Hi @Praveen,
Thank you for your response.

What is the difference from using: 
container.addEventListener("mouseover", function()

and

image1.onmouseover = function(evt)

Answer (score 0):

```
image1.onmouseover = function() {
    image1.src="images/hero.jpg"
};
image1.onmouseout = function() {
    image1.src="images/release.jpg"
};

image2.onmouseover = function() {
    image2.src="images/deer.jpg"
};
image2.onmouseout = function() {
    image2.src="images/bison.jpg"
};
```

};

Comment: please elaborate